# Finding the value of Minkowski's Functional

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X=\mathbb{R}^2$, and $V=B((0,1),2)=$open ball with centre at $(0,1)$ and radius $2.$ Let $x\in X$. I want to find the value of $$ \mu_x=\inf\{ \lambda>0:  x\in \lambda V\}. $$ The above is known as [Minkowski's Funcrional.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_functional)

Comment: Do you mean $x\in \lambda V$ in the infimum?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Hint: write the boundary of $V$ in polar coordinates. (Note that $\mu_x=1$ when $x$ is on the boundary of $V$, and scales linearly along any ray emanating from the origin....)